# How to hide overflow "at the top"?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to hide the overflow of a div "at the top" rather than "at the bottom"?

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fK867/) illustrates what I mean.  The enclosing `div` has `overflow-y:hidden`, but this hides the lower part of its content.  I want to hide the upper part of it.

---

<sub>The obligatory source code (verbatim from the jsFiddle):</sub>

```
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;}
#centered{
  margin:20px auto 0;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  height:150px;
  outline:5px solid green;
}
#centered,
#top,
#bottom{width:150px;}
#top   {height:120px;background-color:red;}
#bottom{height:150px;background-color:#555;}
#top,#bottom{
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:0 10px;
}
#top{padding-top:50px;}
#bottom{padding-top:60px;}
```

```
<div id="centered">
  <div id="top">
    this div should be "overflowed away"
    <em>at the top!</em>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    this content should show
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the content to flow from the bottom up instead of from the top down?

Comment: I'd think that encapsulating everything inside a container, and then aligning that to the bottom should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/eithe/fK867/6/

You'd still need to play around with paddings though.

Answer (score 4):

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fK867/9/), you need to wrap the content in an `absolute` positioned DIV with `bottom` set to 0, whilst the parent container is given a position of `relative`

HTML

```
<div id="centered">
    <div id='content'>
        <div id="top">this div should be "overflowed away" <em>at the top!</em>

        </div>
        <div id="bottom">this content should show</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#centered {
    margin:20px auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:150px;
    border:5px solid green;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
}
#content {
    bottom:0px;
    position:absolute;
}
#top {
    min-height:120px;
    background-color:red;
    padding-top:50px;
}
#bottom {
    background-color:#555;
    padding:60px 10px 0 0;    
}
#top, #bottom {
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/fK867/9/ - there was some badly structured CSS & conflicting properties